# mongodb queries are too slow after upgrading to the latest mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Using
Node JS : 10.15.0,
Mongodb : 4.0.6,
mongodb npm : 3.1.13

upgraded mongodb from 2.6 to the latest 4.0.6 as recommended by the mongodb docs with data(around 20 gb). post upgraded the data is fine but the performance is too slow. queries are getting stuck for 20 sec.

And I tried to rebuild the indexes hence though same problem. How to solve this?

Comment: what is mongodb, mongodb npm? why are these two different versions?

Comment: mongodb is the database, mongodb npm(node_module) which i used to connect mongodb from nodejs

Comment: Buddy, I'm assuming that you're getting a response. This is not an issue then. You need to work on optimizing queries. This issue will always be there when you have lots of data. Googling this issue will get you lots of links that suggest ways to do so.

Comment: Hey buddy, i am clearly telling that, this problem is there after upgrading the mongodb, i have very good optimized code and it is running fine in my older one. try to understand the question first.

Comment: And the person who don't know the difference between mongodb and mongodb npm, pls step back.

Comment: I thought you may want to write mongoose npm & that's the reason, I asked you a question earlier & I'm sure you must be competent enough to figure out why didn't you get an answer yet. The question is so vague, nobody would know what to answer just by looking at it. Let it be, this is not a place to argue.

Comment: @tejas here all competent enough, but u must know y this forum. if everyone fixing their own issues, why we are here?. try to avoid if u dont have time or patience.

Answer (score 1):

in latest version of mongoDB 3.4+, it will consume half of your system RAM and it will be slow in local but will run fast in cloud servers.